# Unintended reaction: Sketch makes LEDs turn on and of randomly/LEDs don't react

Tags: led, sketch, button, debounce

Update: This piece of code does not do the same as the one in the right answer, it also reacts when one lets go of the button.

```
int button_prev = 0;
int button = 0;

void loop(){

    button_prev = button;

    button = digitalRead(12);

    if (button_prev != button) {

      digitalWrite(act_pin[j], HIGH);

      j = (j+1) % 5;

    }
}
```

I printed out j and it seems like, instead of counting up +1 everytime the button is pressed once, it turns +1 and then +1 again which makes two LEDs at a time turn on.
But I don't see where the behavior of j comes from...

[Update: There was a mistake in the code which caused the random behavior, but now, nothing happens when I push the button.]

[I wrote a sketch which is supposed to make the Arduino turn one of five LEDs on one after another every time I press the switch.

But instead of turning one LED on after another, directly after upload it just makes them turn on and of at random. I don't push the button.
`Serial.println` as well just spits out one character, similiar looking to a `d`.]

Can anyone point out my mistake to me?

This is the circuit

[image]

and this is the *old code* of the sketch

```
int act_pin[6] = {A0, A1, A2, A3, A4};

int j = 0;

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);

  for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {

     pinMode(act_pin[k], OUTPUT); //sets analog pins A0 - A4 as output

     digitalWrite(act_pin[k], LOW); //turns LEDs connected to A0 - A4 off

     pinMode(12, INPUT); //sets pin connected to button as input

}

}


void loop(){

  char button = {digitalRead(12)}; //stores if the button was pressed

  Serial.println(button);

  if(button == HIGH){ 

    digitalWrite(act_pin[j], HIGH); //turns LEDs on A0 - A4 on one after one with every button press 

    j = (j+1) % 5; //makes digitalWrite jump to the next LED next time the button is pressed and limits it to 4

    button = LOW; //turns the button's pin low again, so nothing will happen until the button is pressed again
}

}
```

Comment: Other than the fact that you don't do any debouncing?

Comment: Care to explain to me what you mean by debouncing? (And if it could be the cause of the problem.)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce

Comment: Okey, I edited the question: I don't even press the button before the failure happens. Also: "The effect is usually unimportant in power circuits, but causes problems in some analogue and logic circuits that respond fast enough to misinterpret the on‑off pulses as a data stream." and I am not using an analog input or output(I do use the analog pins, right, but with digitalWrite).

Comment: A MCU is a giant logic circuit.

Comment: The debouncing that you should be worried about is that your code loops so fast, even pressing the button for an instant activates the "button is pressed" code multiple times. you need to recognize when the button has turned from off to on, not just when it is pressed.

Comment: You might want to add a `delay`, or the leds will turn on, one after another, faster than your eyes can see.

Comment: @BrettM I already thought that this could be a problem, but as Gerben said, this would make the lamps turn on very fast. Right now, the lamps do not react at all.

Comment: @Gerben See the comment above this one.

Comment: change "button" to a boolean and the serial output will start making sense; with more understandable serial output how about putting a large delay in the loop (1s maybe?) and then looking at the output to see if button is reacting correctly.

Comment: @BrettM I put a delay of 2 sec at the end of the if. When I output button as a boolean, I get 0 until I press it, when, because of the delay, the output stops, then, I get a 1 and then it goes back to writing 0. So I think the button is reacting correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the action (in pseudo-code):

```
ONCE (Button Pressed):
    Light LED j;
    j++
```

But you have an IF(button) in a Loop{}. Something like:

```
WHILE (Button Pressed):
    Light LED j;
    j++
```

So when you press the button j will increment every iteration of Loop {}  (very fast) and you won't be able to see the LEDs changing. Your 'button = LOW' is not effective because 'button' gets set again the next time if the button is still pressed.

Try printing j instead of button at the line:

```
Serial.println(j);
```

and that should highlight the problem.

I would implement a ONCE(Button Pressed) function by observing the previous button state and checking it has changed from LOW to HIGH.

```
    button_prev = button;
    button = digitalRead(12);
// Check if button changed from LOW to HIGH
    if (!button_prev && button) {
    ...code
    }
```

EDIT: Dealing with Contact Bounce

Switches are mechanical so they don't switch cleanly. This is called contact bounce and means the switch switches on/off very rapidly for about 10ms or so after the contact has been pressed or released.

See [Measuring Switch Bounce](http://www.picotech.com/experiments/switch_bounce/measuring-switch-bounce.html)

[image]

You can deal with it quite simply in the code as follows (pseudo code) just by waiting for the bounce to dissapear and checking the button is still pressed:

```
ONCE (Button Pressed):
   WAIT(20ms)              // wait for the bounce to stop
   IF(Button Pressed):     // Ensure the button is still pressed
    ...code...
```

Try the following Arduino Code:

```
    button_prev = button;
    button = digitalRead(12);
// Check if button changed from LOW to HIGH
    if (!button_prev && button) {
       delay(20);                 // Wait for debounce
       if(digitalRead(12))  {     // Make sure the button is still pressed
        ...code
       }
    }
```

Comment: So, I wrote a piece of code which works so far, as the LEDs do react to the button, but somehow, they always turn on two at a time. See edit.

Comment: I found the error. I wrote the piece of code different from yours because I didn't fully understood your if statement when I first read it(hadn't used boolean operators in C yet), but I thought my code does the same as yours, while it does not. It also reacts when I let the button go. You solution is right, thank you!

Comment: You say the LEDs also change when you release the button? That's just contact bounce which means the switch bounces on/off for about 10ms after you've pressed it (on or off) due to the mechanical nature of the switch contacts. I'll add a section to my answer on how to deal with that.

Comment: No, that wasn't because of the bouncing, but because of a mistake of mine in the if statement. It became true if I pushed button, but as well when I released it but I used your statement and now it works just fine. What, indeed, is caused by debouncing, is that the program sometimes processes two pins at a time instead of just one.

Comment: Thanks for the code, I think I'll rather use that one instead of the code from the Arduino site(which is probably basically the same, but it seems far more complicated to me).

Comment: Your way of debouncing works, I didn't think it would be that easy to do, thanks! :) (Would mark your answer right a second time, if I could.)

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a serious bug here:

```
if(button == HIGH){ 

    digitalWrite(act_pin[j], HIGH);

    j = j+1;

    button = LOW;
}
```

You increment `j` without any boundary so it will have the following cycling values:

```
0, 1, 2, 3 ... 32767, -32768, -32767 ... -1, 0 ...
```

Hence, quickly `act_pin[j]` will return garbage...

The solution is easy, you must limit `j` to `[0,1,2,3,4]`, just replace the `j = j + 1` line as follows:

```
j = (j + 1) % 5;
```

`%` is the modulo integral operation that will give you the reminder of dividing j by 5, which is always strictly less than 5, and it cycles as you want.

Comment: Thanks, I did that, this does not solve the problem about the lamps not reacting. (Actually in the whole context of the project it wouldn't make sense to press the button more than five times, so I did not thought about a limit, but still, its much cleaner like this, thank you!)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if(button = HIGH)
> ```

Oops.

```
if (button == HIGH)
```

And see the [Debounce example sketch](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Debounce) to learn how to debounce inputs.

Comment: Oh...okey. I am a blind man. The random on-off stopped. But now nothing happens when I push the button, could this be because of this debouncing? I am just wondering because I did something similar with a button before(the second project in the starter book), and there was no concern about debouncing whatsoever.

Comment: As they say there: "Without debouncing, pressing the button once can appear to the code as multiple presses." but nothing happens when I press the button.

Comment: None of the LEDs turn on?

Comment: Yes, none. I also tried pushing longer, but I get no reaction.

Comment: The braces around the call to `digitalRead()` are suspect. Remove them.

Comment: Changes nothing. I also tried giving `button` a fixed length of `[6]`(HIGH + \0) but that returns the same result.